# Instantiating a class that inherits INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged, instantiation

I have a very simple class that has a single property and which inherits INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
class SimpleClass:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _property;
    public string Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set
        {
            _property = value; 
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs"Property"));
        }
    }
}
```

I try to instantiate a SimpleClass object in the constructor for a WPF Window but I get the following TargetInvocationException: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation".
If I remove the INotifyPropertyChange inheritance (and any reference to the PropertyChanged event) then I don't get the error and my project runs without any problems. Any ideas why?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't checking for null on `PropertyChanged`.

if nobody is listening, then it will be null.  most people protect for the event listeners to change during the event, as well:

```
var listeners = PropertyChanged;
if (listeners != null)
    listeners(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Property");
```

Comment: Yea good catch. that will be the exception being caused by the listerners being null.

Comment: Thanks! By the way why did you use listeners rather than PropertyChanged directly like Chris Shain's answer below?

Comment: it's a very common pattern, even the msdn *how to implement...* does it that way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx  .  I've *heard* that if you're doing multithreaded stuff, the property PropertyChanged *could* change between the `if` and the block of code inside.  the local value can not.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in this code is obviously causing that error.  We'd need more information to be sure what's going on.  The hints you gave about INotifyPropertyChanged, however, lead me to believe its that your PropertyChanged event is null, and you don't have a null check around it.  You either need to add the null check:

```
    set
    {
        _property = value; 
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs"Property"));
    }
```

or ensure that the event is never null:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (s, e) => { };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the brackets () after the class name:

```
public class SimpleClass:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _property;
    public string Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set
        {
            _property = value; 
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Property"));
        }
    }
}
```